# Create property of UserControl Instances (not new)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a usercontrol where I want a property that can list all the other instances of the same usercontrols in the Windows Form.

Eg. I have a simple usercontrol (sidebarbutton). I drag-drop 2 instances of it in a UserForm. Now I want a property (in the usercontrol itself) that can list both of them.

I have written this property. However, when used in Property Browser Window of Visual Studio, it allows me to add ***new*** instances of sidebarButton control.

```
private List<SidebarButton> _sidebarButtons;

[Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), Category("Roshan")]
public List<SidebarButton> SidebarButtons
{
    get { return this._sidebarButtons; }
    set { this._sidebarButtons = value; }
}
```

How to add the 2 instances that I drag-droped in the form in this property.
I know the property needs to be modified but don't have a proper direction to take. Please HELP me.

Comment: This is a very odd use case... Controls should stand on their own and not need knowledge about other controls. Data transfer should be done by the business logic (which already knows about all controls/data).

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this could be that upon addition of the user control to the form, the user control notifies all other user controls of that type that it now exists. Your user control can implement an interface like so:

```
public interface INotifiable
{
    public void AddToList(INotifiable newButton);
}
```

When the user control is added to the form you iterate through all the controls and check whether they implement this interface. If they do you call the `AddToList` method and pass the newly added control to it.